How to touch down without touch up for iphone in appium python
Im using XCuitest for iphone in python appium.
my current code
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.w3c_actions = ActionBuilder(driver, mouse=PointerInput(interaction.POINTER_TOUCH, "touch"))
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to_location(240, 1420)
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.pointer_down()

    actions.perform()
    

for android its working nicely. but for iphone, after perfom its look like touch up. i want to hold touch down.
